# Excel access.Vlookup? IF?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, database, vlookup

What I am looking to do, is to move stuff from one excel sheet to another sheet, in the same workbook.

We will call the sheet with the data the "suppliers list" and the sheet where I want it to go, the "completed list".

On the suppliers list it will list,

- Name of company,
- address
- phone
- fax
- person of contact
- cell
- email
- federal id

On the completed list, there will be multiple boxes. In those boxes I want to be able to select 
the name of company, and have Excel or Access auto-fill in the rest of the information down the rest of the columns. Basically, a time saver rather than typing everything out.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use either one (Access or Excel) to do what you wanted.

Main difference: 
On Access you simply populate the table "Supplier List" and then create a form on access so that you can select a company name from a drop down menu on the form, and the form will fill out all the other details based on the details on the Supplier List table.

On Excel you do lots of VLOOKUPs.

1. You need to create a Selectable List (as per to your requirement) on "Completed List" page
2. You apply VLOOKUP on the list to populate the "Completed List" table
3. Caveat: VLOOKUP requires the name of the company (or whatever you are using as the ID must be sorted alphabetically, or from smaller to higher)

How to make a list and drop down menu is available here: [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Create-a-Drop-Down-List-in-Excel).

For example your drop down menu is on cell A2 (CompletedList), and your data are in "SupplierList" between A2:H50 then your formula on B2 (CompletedList) is something like:

```
=VLOOKUP(B2, SupplierList!A2:H50, 2)
```

Your B2 will have drop down menu with the company name. The above will pick up 
Address. Then on C2, you do something similar but simply change the last index to 3. Then on D2, you do as above, change the last index to 4, and keep going until you are finished.

Edited to add (based on the comments):

Simply copy the drop down menu (on B2) on more cells below it (B3 onwards), and copy all the VLOOKUP downwards as well, and then you have a column (B for example) full of Cells that are all Drop Down menu, and all the remaining cells to the right (C, D, etc) with the VLOOKUP result.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Perfect, the only thing i need to figure out is, i need the information from the supplier list, to fill out all the spots on the "completed list" several times, the end supplier list will have several of the suppliers listed. 

So basically ill "pick" which suppliers need to go on the list probably 20 or so. I can show you a completed oen if that would help :)